# fopen works on local server but not on webserver

Tags: php, fopen

I'm using `fopen` to create a new file.  On my localserver it works fine, however on my webserver (linux shared hosting with goDaddy) I get:

> Warning: fopen(invoices/qbImport519.iif) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/c/h/i/chiseled/html/tracking_admin/qbInvoices.php on line 97

Thinking that it was settings on the webserver, I contacted GoDaddy who responded that everything was setup on my account correctly for this to work.  Any ideas?

Here's is my code:

```
  $qbFile = fopen("invoices/qbImport".$Hits.".iif","ab");
  if (is_writable("invoices/qbImport".$Hits.".iif")){
    if (fwrite($qbFile,$iifWrite)){
      echo'<a href="invoices/qbImport'.$Hits.'.iif">Download Your File</a><br/>';
      else {
        echo "<p>Cannot add your entry</p>";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "<p>The file is not writeable</p>";
    }
  fclose($qbFile);
```

I have tried the paths `/home/content/c/h/i/chiseled/html/tracking_admin/invoices` and `invoices/`.

The file does not exists since it's based on the `$hits` variable which is incremented each time. So for some reason it's not able to create the new file. I have also tried just `a` for the `fopen` mode.

Any help would be great. thanks.

Comment: And you're sure the path exists and you have write permission?

Comment: Well, what are the permissions of the folder you try to create a file inside? And what is the account the web server runs under?

Comment: Does the path `home/content/c/h/i/chiseled/html/tracking_admin/` actually exist? fwrite won't create the directory for you, and the web server must have write access to it.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies.
I am a moron. I had created the directory as "Invoices" not "invoices".
Can I knock down my own reputation points? lol

Answer (score 0):

I had created the directory as "Invoices" not "invoices". No more coding till 4am!

Answer (score 0):

it is because fwrite is not supported in godaddy. godaddy has alot of restriction. It is better you go with other good hosts like bluehost, ipage. Godaddy may be good in domains but hosting is poor. even wordpress won't run perfectly in godaddy.

Matt Mullenweg the creator of wordpress says that
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/more-godaddy-installation-problems